# Datetime.Today in GMT in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I want to convert `DateTime.Today` to GMT time.

i.e. If I am in L.A. and it is 11pm of 22/02/2012 I want DateTime.Today to be 23/02/2012 because it will be that day in GMT time.

Comment: With GMT you mean UTC, and not `Europe/London`, right?

Comment: Since this question was the starting point of some controversy, I take the opportunity to promote [Earth Standard Time](http://xkcd.com/1061/).

Comment: @filburt - LOL! that is so hilarious! but i think most of the humor comes from being familiar with the whole UTC claims and various calendar & time standards. but absolutely hilarious! thx for sharing! i had to save that pic!

Answer (score 183, accepted):

There is no `DateTime.UtcToday`, but you can try `DateTime.UtcNow.Date`

Comment: i came here wondering whether DateTime.Today returned the date of the local time or the date of the UtcTime. this question and answer answers my question! thx!

Comment: Decompiling DateTime.Today results in:  `public static DateTime Today { get { return DateTime.Now.Date; } }`

Answer (score -1):

DateTime LocalToGMT = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset.Hours);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31464762)

Answer (score -2):

`DateTime.UtcNow` will give you the current universal time.

Comment: Totally irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Chamkila only thing OP needed to do was write .Date after this, as can be seen in accepted answer.

Comment: Was perfectly balanced at +9/-9